# Combinatorics question about putting a number of men and women in a line

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

**The questions is:** A group of people contains 5 men and 6 women. How many different lines can be formed using any 2 of the men and any 3 of the women?

I'm confused about how the selecting of a certain number of individuals out of the men and women affects the formula, along with whether the order matters in this.

Comment: Since they speak of lines, I'd assume that order mattered.

Comment: They want you to select two of the five men and three of the six women, then arrange the five people you have selected in a line.   Order matters.